# Execute a command after sudo

Tags: linux, bash, centos

**The Background**

I am working in a CentOS environment with numerous CentOS machines. Currently there are multiple developers that each have their own login/home directory and then for various admin tasks we all share a single super user account.

**The problem**

I have a number of aliases, variables, functions, and settings that exist in my personal login's .bash_profile. None of these are available in the shared super user's .bash_profile. My current work around is that everytime I sudo in as the super user and I re-execute my .bash_profile from my personal user's home directory. I am not allowed to edit the init stuff for the super user

**The Question**

Is there any way I can automate my sudo sequence such that it will execute my personal .bash_profile after I've executed sudo without requiring me to edit the super user's bash init stuff?

Comment: How is this off topic? Its about as objective and related to software development as anything gets.

Comment: Votes to close are alway subjective but this seems like a pretty general environment setup question.  It may seem development related to you because that is your immediate objective but it could just as easily be asked by someone looking to setup any admin tasks.

Comment: ummm.... "seem development related" . How is it different than say this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853451/can-the-find-commands-exec-feature-start-a-program-in-the-background where the user is asking a question about "find" like I am asking a question about "sudo"

Comment: As I recall that question preceded the existence of superuser, serverfault, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep aliases by this neat little trick:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

Which allows for the next argument to be checked for alias expansion (from your current profile!)

From man alias:

> A trailing space  in value  causes the  next  word  to  be checked for alias substitution when the alias is expanded.

YMMV for the functions, etc.

The env_reset in /etc/sudoers is the other workaround I've found.

http://blog.edwards-research.com/2010/07/keeping-aliases-with-sudo-sort-of/

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` has an option to retain the environment of the person invoking it albeit with some caveats. From the manual page

> -E          The -E (preserve
>   environment) option will override the
>   env_reset option in sudoers(5)).  It
>   is only available when
>                      either the matching command has the SETENV tag or the
>   setenv option is set in sudoers(5).

Comment: No dice - user is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - top -E' as root on <host>

Comment: It should be `sudo -E top`, not `su - top -E`.

Comment: Not sure if its a version difference but the man page for sudo includes no -E switch in the environment I'm using

Comment: I think you're out of luck then.

Answer (score 1):

edit /etc/sudoers (visudo)

create or modify the Defaults env_keep variable

```
Defaults    env_keep = "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR \
                        LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR"
```

This will keep the specified environment variables in your environment after the sudo has executed.

Or comment out Defaults env_reset, but note that this is dangerous!

```
#Defaults    env_reset
```

This keeps the entire environemt from the shell before the sudo executed.